# Excel If Match Formula Help Needed

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Can someone please help me with the following excel formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A81,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product")
```

The formula works however, when I drag the formula down to blank cells the formula displays “Sold Out Product” and I would like the formula to display nothing for blanks cells

[image: Screenshot of Formula and Results]

Revised Screenshot of Formula and Results

[image: Revised Screenshot of Formula and Results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it to test if the cell is empty :

```
=IF(A81<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A81,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product"),"")
```

So for the 2nd row :

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product"),"")
```

Comment: @ComputerNovice : My bad, I used `;` instead of `,` that you had!

Comment: Thanks @R3uK it still doesn't work. I have uploaded an image of the spreadsheet to my original post

Comment: @ComputerNovice : Did you use it in the right row? Are the cells in col A really empty?

Comment: Yes @R3uK, I have attached a revised screenshot of the outcome

Comment: @ComputerNovice : Try to use Formula Evaluator under the Formulae tab. Because the result is pretty surprising! What is the value of A25 and the result of the Match()?

Comment: @ComputerNovice I can see from the screenshot that you are using the wrong references. You used formula `=IF(A25<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product"),"")` in cell `C425`, so you need to change the formula to reflect that. `A25` and `A2` should be `A425`. Try to put the following formula in `C425` and see if it works: `=IF(A425<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A425,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product"),"")`

Comment: Thanks @VictorMoraes - The following formula now works =IF(A425<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A425,$E:$E,0)),"Sold Out Product","Existing Product"),"")

Comment: Thanks again @R3uK

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A81,$E:$E,0)),"","Existing Product")
```

Comment: Thanks, this will not work as it needs to say either Existing Product, Sold Out Product or leave the cell blank